# Mapping data from dataframe to another to pull out information users

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with the customers who prefer songs, and my other dataframe consists of users and their cluster.

DATA 1:

```
user    song
A   11
A   22
B   22
B   33
C   11
D   44
C   33
E   11
D   33
```

DATA 2:

```
user    cluster
A   1
B   2
C   1
D   2
E   1
```

I got all the songs listened by cluster's, as shown below.

```
cluster songs
1   11, 22, 33
2   22,33, 44
```

I want it to output the songs which was not listened by a user of that particular cluster.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
user    song
A   [33]
B   [44]
C   [11,22]
D   [22]
E   [22,33]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join and [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='user', how='left').drop_duplicates(['cluster','song'])
print (df)
  user  song  cluster
0    A    11        1
1    A    22        1
2    B    22        2
3    B    33        2
5    C    33        1
```

Then aggregate `join`, but before is necessary convert `songs` to strings:

```
df = df['song'].astype(str).groupby(df['cluster']).apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   cluster        song
0        1  11, 22, 33
1        2      22, 33
```

Or if need `list`s:

```
df = df.groupby('cluster')['song'].apply(list).reset_index()
#same as
#df = df['song'].groupby(df['cluster']).apply(list).reset_index()

print (df)
   cluster          song
0        1  [11, 22, 33]
1        2      [22, 33]
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='user', how='left').drop_duplicates(['user','song'])
df1 = df.pivot('user','song', 'cluster')

df3 = df1.isnull().stack().reset_index(name='val')
df3 = df3[df3['val']].groupby('user')['song'].apply(list).reindex(df2['user'])
print (df3)
user
A        [33]
B        [11]
C        [22]
D        [11]
E    [22, 33]
Name: song, dtype: object
```

Comment: is there any specific reason that you put cluster == 1 in your query ? ** .query('cluster == 1') **

Comment: @pylearner - I think you want filter only cluster `1`. I am wrong?

Comment: @pylearner - Because if remove it, get a bit different output.

Comment: I need the data for every cluster

Comment: @pylearner - OK, then simply remove `.query('cluster == 1') `

Comment: Hey ' user B ' belongs to cluster 2, so he dont need to listen to song -11 .

Comment: I want them to listen only what cluster suggests them to listen

Comment: @pylearner - I am confused. Do you need filter for all clusters? Or dor cluster 1 and cluster 2 separately?

Comment: for my data I have 25 clusters ...I want for all clusters seperately ..

Comment: If you see my expected output, A belongs to cluster 1, and he has not listened to song 33, which was listened by other user in cluster 1, so i want A to listen to song 33 ..

Comment: Can you add more data with expected output? And better create new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927671/assigning-the-value-to-a-user-depending-on-the-cluster-he-comes-from

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
In [861]: df1.groupby(df1.user.map(df2.set_index('user')['cluster']))['song'].unique()
Out[861]:
user
1    [11, 22, 33]
2        [22, 33]
Name: song, dtype: object
```

Or

```
In [857]: df1.groupby(df1.user.map(df2.set_index('user')['cluster']))['song'].agg(
               lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique().astype(str)))
Out[857]:
user
1    11, 22, 33
2        22, 33
Name: song, dtype: object
```

Comment: may be do a `.reset_index().rename(columns={'user':'cluster'})` at the end just to really complete it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty efficient solution using `map` + `groupby` + `unique`:

```
mapper = df1.user.map(df2.set_index('user').cluster)
df1.song.groupby(mapper).unique()

user
1    [11, 22, 33]
2        [22, 33]
Name: song, dtype: object
```

Gets you a list of values per cluster.

Comment: Can  you get me the column names as cluster, songs for the two column output ?

Answer (score 0):

In one line

```
data1.merge(data2,left_on='ser',right_on='user').groupby('cluster').song.unique()
```

Output:

```
cluster
1    [11, 22, 33]
2        [22, 33]
Name: song, dtype: object
```