# assigning the value to a user depending on the cluster he comes from

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes, one with the customers who prefer songs, and my other dataframe consists of users and their cluster.

DATA 1:

```
user    song
A   11
A   22
B   99
B   11
C   11
D   44
C   66
E   66
D   33
E   55
F   11
F   77
```

DATA 2:

```
user    cluster
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   1
E   2
F   3
```

Using above data sets, I was able to achieve what all songs are listened by users of that cluster.

```
cluster songs
    1   [11, 22, 33, 44]
    2   [11, 99, 66, 55] 
    3   [11,66,88,77]
```

I need to assign the song of a particular cluster to that particular user who has not listened to it yet.
In my expected output A belongs to cluster 1, and he has not yet listened to song 33 and 44..so my output should be like below. Same for B, which belongs to cluster 2, B has not listen to 66 and 55 songs, output for B looks like below.

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
  user  song
    A   [33, 44]
    B   [66,55]
    C   [77]
    D   [11,22]
    E   [11,99]
    F   [66]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy:

```
#add column and remove duplicates
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='user', how='left').drop_duplicates(['user','song'])

def f(x):
    #for each group reshape
    x = x.pivot('user','song','cluster')
    #get all columns values if NaNs in data  
    x = x.apply(lambda x: x.index[x.isnull()].tolist(),1)
    return x

df1 = df.groupby(['cluster']).apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()
user
A    [33, 44]
B    [55, 66]
C        [77]
D    [11, 22]
E    [11, 99]
F        [66]
dtype: object
```

Similar solution:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='user', how='left').drop_duplicates(['user','song'])
df1 = (df.groupby(['cluster']).apply(lambda x: x.pivot('user','song','cluster').isnull())
        .fillna(False)
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .sort_index())

#replace each True by value of column
s = np.where(df1, ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df1.columns.astype(str)], '')
#remove empty values
s1 = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df1.index)
print (s1)
user
A    33, 44
B    55, 66
C        77
D    11, 22
E    11, 99
F        66
dtype: object
```

Comment: one can praise anyone, for me its YOU...  'THE GOD' .

Comment: @pylearner - Thank you, really help me your very nice sample data ;) Good luck!

Comment: In your first solution, can you make the df1 as a dataframe with two columns, user and songs

Comment: Simply add `.reset_index()` like `df1 = df.groupby(['cluster']).apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index().reset_index(name='song')`

Comment: jez, can you tell what this `x = x.apply(lambda x: x.index[x.isnull()].tolist(),1)` is doing in your above solution no 1 ??

Comment: It is only alternative, but it create strings instead lists. So I think it cannot be used fo your list like solutions.

Comment: it worked for me, but just trying to understand what it does after the pivoting

Comment: Can you help me out on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883875/mapping-columns-of-two-data-frames-and-adding-a-value-from-the-list

Comment: @pylearner - Hmmm, I see your question and seems a bit complicated, so no answering. It use more pure python as pure pandas and it is a bit harder for me and need more google nice ideas and functions. So sorry. Good luck! Btw, I think now is a lot good answerers, so I think get a lot of nice answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use sets for comparison.

**Setup**

```
df1

#    user  song
# 0     A    11
# 1     A    22
# 2     B    99
# 3     B    11
# 4     C    11
# 5     D    44
# 6     C    66
# 7     E    66
# 8     D    33
# 9     E    55
# 10    F    11
# 11    F    77

df2

#   user  cluster
# 0    A        1
# 1    B        2
# 2    C        3
# 3    D        1
# 4    E        2
# 5    F        3

df3

#    cluster             songs
# 0        1  [11, 22, 33, 44]
# 1        2  [11, 99, 66, 55]
# 2        3  [11, 66, 88, 77]
```

**Calculation**

```
df = df1.groupby('user')['song'].apply(set)\
        .reset_index().rename(columns={'song': 'heard'})

df['all'] = df['user'].map(df2.set_index('user')['cluster'])\
                      .map(df3.set_index('cluster')['songs'])\
                      .map(set)

df['not heard'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['all'] - row['heard'], axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
  user     heard               all not heard
0    A  {11, 22}  {33, 11, 44, 22}  {33, 44}
1    B  {11, 99}  {99, 66, 11, 55}  {66, 55}
2    C  {66, 11}  {88, 66, 11, 77}  {88, 77}
3    D  {33, 44}  {33, 11, 44, 22}  {11, 22}
4    E  {66, 55}  {99, 66, 11, 55}  {11, 99}
5    F  {11, 77}  {88, 66, 11, 77}  {88, 66}
```

Extract any columns you need; conversion to list is trivial, i.e. `df[col] = df[col].map(list)`.

**Explanation**

There are 3 steps:

1. Convert lists to sets and aggregate heard songs by user to sets.
2. Perform mappings to put all data in one table.
3. Add a column which calculates the difference between 2 sets.

Comment: in place of my cluster values, I have float values ... its throwing me an error saying "" TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable""

Comment: @pylearner, I can't replicate your error. Feel free to provide a [mcve] if you want to find out what's going wrong.